# Ubuntu necesita AntiVirus?

Tags: server

Apenas voy a iniciar con Ubuntu, básicamente que necesito saber de Ubuntu? respecto a las impresoras que hoy en día están instaladas en la compañía y con software que se trabajan, y que tipo de licencias pagas se requieren para trabajar Ubuntu, o antivirus requeridos.
Agradezco la información que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Ask Ubuntu es un sitio de inglés. Por favor, uses [Google Translate](http://translate.google.es) para traducir su pregunta a inglés.

Comment: in english please!

Comment: [EN] This question is excessively broad in its scope. It should be either closed or taken off AU.  I'd favor supressing it, not just for the fact that it is Spanish, although its author did not bother translating it.  -----  [ES] Esta pregunta es excesivamente amplia en lo que abarca. Al no conformar con las normas de AU debería ser cerrada o suprimida de AU ( el uso del Español es un mal menor en este caso, aunque el autor no se ha dignado en traducirla ).

Answer (score 0):

Deves usar antivirus para tus aplicativos windows que instalas en tu linux. Se no usas aplicativos windows no lo necessitas de antivirus no linux.

Puedes usar lo ClamAV antivirus pero no es necessário.

Comment: AV es necesario para unas cosas. Emails pueden tener viruses. Es mejor que lo haga claro. Also, Ask Ubuntu is an English site, so even if the question is in Spanish, you need to answer in English.